# generate Multiple UUID Oracle

Tags: oracle, uuid

Oracle:-
I have around 850 records in an table, that need to be assigned UUID.

I am using the following query.

```
select substr(sys_guid(),1,3)||'-'||
          substr(sys_guid(),4,4)||'-'||
          substr(sys_guid(),8,4)||'-'||
          substr(sys_guid(),13)
from (select sys_guid() as mygid from dual)
```

I need to generate multiple/850 records in one go.
Any suggestions ?
Should I loop over?

Comment: you have 2 bugs. **1.** use `mygid` instead of `sys_guid` in outer select. **2.** last `substr` should begin with 12, not 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need `select`, use hierarchical query:

```
SELECT Substr(mygid,1,3)||'-'||
       Substr(mygid,4,4)||'-'||
       Substr(mygid,8,4)||'-'||
       Substr(mygid,12)
  FROM (
        SELECT Sys_GUID() AS mygid FROM dual
        CONNECT BY Level <= :desired_number_of_records
       )
```

But what's wrong with usual `update` ?

```
UPDATE your_tab
   SET gid_col = (
         SELECT Substr(mygid,1,3)||'-'||
                Substr(mygid,4,4)||'-'||
                Substr(mygid,8,4)||'-'||
                Substr(mygid,12)
           FROM( SELECT Sys_Guid() AS mygid FROM dual ) 
         )
```

Comment: while using  UPDATE my_tab
   SET some_col = Sys_GUID()

Comment: I am not sure I will be able to generate the format I want like

Comment: @Fransis: I forgot about format, my bad. Use scalar query. I've updated my answer. (b.t.w. why didn't you write all in one comment ? :) )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that format is really what you want as you are missing 9 of the 32 characters, buy you could modify the format as needed. Here is an example that shows how to format like XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET GUID_COL = (
  select regexp_replace((rawtohex(sys_guid()), '([A-F0-9]{8})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{4})([A-F0-9]{12})', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5') as FORMATTED_GUID from dual
)
```